# Apple Sign-In Dialog Box not appearing when fetching Storekit Products

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, apple-sign-in

1. I am trying to fetch the In App Purchase Products in my screen but I am not being asked to enter the Apple ID. In fact I am not getting the Sign-In Dialogue Box at all. I have signed out of the device and tried logging in with Sandbox account in the Settings and I still see there is no prompt to enter the Sandbox Apple Login. Am I missing anything here?
2. My IAP is in Ready to Submit state and I am getting
   **InvalidIdentifiers** for all the Product ID's that have been in Ready to Submit state. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I got to found the answer.

1. We need to Sign Out from the Sandbox accounts from
   Settings->AppStore-> Sandbox Account and try the Sandbox Testing. It
   should work.

[image: Screenshot showing the Settings]

2. I found the answer for this in this Link https://stackoverflow.com/a/30306005/208308. Please make sure the Paid Agreements are approved. This was the reason in my case.

Comment: I encountered the same issue when I upgraded from the original API to StoreKit2. Signed out of sandbox account and everything started to work as expected.